# .htaccess rewrite rules for "/", "/index.html"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

having trouble with this .htaccess file for [www.gardening-services-edinburgh.com/index.html](http://www.gardening-services-edinburgh.com/index.html)

currently

our .htaccess looks like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gardening-services-edinburgh.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gardening-services-edinburgh.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]                              
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What is the trouble?

Comment: trying to get the example.com/index.html to default to "example.com/"

Comment: Is mod-rewrite enabled?

Comment: nope, but the example.com rewrite to www.example.com works

Comment: the "RewriteEngine on" so do i need the mod-rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gardening-services-edinburgh.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gardening-services-edinburgh.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.+/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0/ [R=301,L]
```